# GetView extended from BaseAdapter is not running with Runnable Task

Tags: android, android-fragments

I know, it's a very common topic.
I'm following all the threads and documentation about this behavior, but any solutions works for me.

I have my adapter:
**ListAdapter**

```
public class ListAdapterForFragment extends BaseAdapter {

    NewsFragment main;

    public ListAdapterForFragment(NewsFragment main){
        this.main = main;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return  main.countries.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    static class ViewHolderItem {
        TextView name;
        TextView code;
        ImageView imageView2;
        TextView id;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        ViewHolderItem holder = new ViewHolderItem();
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) main.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cell, null);

            //asigning all the holders and values
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolderItem) convertView.getTag();
        }

        //More code

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

**MyFragment**

```
public void onViewCreated(View v, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(v, savedInstanceState);
    //super.onPostExecute(result);
    text.setText("hola mundo");

    adapter = new ListAdapterForFragment(this);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        }
    });

    Download_data download_data = new Download_data((Download_data.download_complete) this);
    download_data.download_data_from_link("http://cloud.anda.gob.sv/sm/Home/ObtenerDenunciasNoResueltas");
}

@Override
public void get_data(String data) {
    try {
        JSONArray data_array = new JSONArray(data);

        for (int i = 0; i < data_array.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(data_array.get(i).toString());

            Den add = new Den();
            add.type = obj.getString("type");
            add.desc = obj.getString("desc");
            add.PhotoURL = obj.getString("URL");
            add.Id = Integer.parseInt(obj.getString("Id"));
            add.Latitud = Double.parseDouble(obj.getString("Latitud"));
            add.Longitud = Double.parseDouble(obj.getString("Longitud"));
            countries.add(add);
        }

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The adapter is executing the `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` and the first time, `main.countries.size();` returns 0, but after that returns 6.
But, the method `GetView()` is not executed.
How I can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it work if you call setAdapter after you build your countries list?

The code you have included is not very clear. Is there an AsyncTask somewhere?